# Jenkins build cannot find resources but maven does

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, maven-antrun-plugin

I am trying to setup Jenkins to automate project builds and I ran to the following problem. mvn clean install works perfectly from cmd but project build from jenkins fails when maven-antrun-plugin is being used.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.7:run
(clientgen) on project Sample: 
An Ant BuildException has occured: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for 
details.
[ERROR] around Ant part ...<javac fork="yes" memoryInitialSize="512m" 
destdir="E:\Jenkins\workspace\Trunk Builds\Sample\target/generated-sources" 
memoryMaximumSize="1024m" srcdir="E:\Jenkins\workspace\Trunk Builds\Sample\target/build"
source="1.4" classpathref="maven.plugin.classpath" executable="C:\j2sdk1.4.2_19/bin/javac" 
target="1.4"/>... @ 46:428 in 
E:\Jenkins\workspace\Trunk Builds\Sample\target\antrun\build-main.xml
```

Jenkins is actually unable to check for the packages imported when I use maven-antrun-plugin.

```
[javac] E:/Jenkins/workspace/Trunk Builds/Sample/target/build/ClassSample.java:20: 
package org.sample.package does not exist
```

Whenever I do not use maven-antrun-plugin Jenkin build succeeds. Any ideas why even though it works through cmd jenkins fail to build the project?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found the real problem and found a workaround. The problem is that Jenkins did not access .m2/repository for some reason so I configured Jenkins to use local to workspace repository. Now it builds normally.